# 2nd item in slider is not showing on the web page on execution

Tags: javascript, arrays, slider, review

I'm making a reviews slider in JavaScript. The problem I'm facing is that while I run the code it doesn't show the 2nd item in the array. Could anybody see the code and tell me what possibly is the error in the below code?

```
**HTML**

  <body>
    <main>
      <section class="container">
        <!-- title -->
        <div class="title">
          <h2>our reviews</h2>
          <div class="underline"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- review -->
        <article class="review">
          <div class="img-container">
            <img src="person-1.jpeg" id="person-img" alt="" />
          </div>
          <h4 id="author">sara jones</h4>
          <p id="job">ux designer</p>
          <p id="info">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto
            asperiores debitis incidunt, eius earum ipsam cupiditate libero?
            Iste, doloremque nihil?
          </p>
          <!-- prev next buttons-->
          <div class="button-container">
            <button class="prev-btn">
              <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
            </button>
            <button class="next-btn">
              <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <!-- random button -->
          <button class="random-btn">surprise me</button>
        </article>
      </section>
    </main>
    <!-- javascript -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

**javascript:**
const reviews = [

    {
        id: 1,
        name: "susan smith",
        job: "web developer",
        img:
          "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883334/person-1_rfzshl.jpg",
        text:
          "I'm baby meggings twee health goth +1. Bicycle rights tumeric chartreuse before they sold out chambray pop-up. Shaman humblebrag pickled coloring book salvia hoodie, cold-pressed four dollar toast everyday carry",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "anna johnson",
        job: "web designer",
        img:
          "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883409/person-2_np9x5l.jpg",
        text:
          "Helvetica artisan kinfolk thundercats lumbersexual blue bottle. Disrupt glossier gastropub deep v vice franzen hell of brooklyn twee enamel pin fashion axe.photo booth jean shorts artisan narwhal.",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "peter jones",
        job: "intern",
        img:
          "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883417/person-3_ipa0mj.jpg",
        text:
          "Sriracha literally flexitarian irony, vape marfa unicorn. Glossier tattooed 8-bit, fixie waistcoat offal activated charcoal slow-carb marfa hell of pabst raclette post-ironic jianbing swag.",
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "bill anderson",
        job: "the boss",
        img:
          "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883423/person-4_t9nxjt.jpg",
        text:
          "Edison bulb put a bird on it humblebrag, marfa pok pok heirloom fashion axe cray stumptown venmo actually seitan. VHS farm-to-table schlitz, edison bulb pop-up 3 wolf moon tote bag street art shabby chic. ",
      },
];
//select items
const img = document.getElementById('person-img');
const author = document.getElementById('author');
const job = document.getElementById('job');
const info = document.getElementById('info');
//select buttons
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prev-btn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next-btn');
const randomBtn = document.querySelector('.random-btn');
//set starting item
let currentItem = 0;//as arrays start from zero                         
//load initial item
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    showPerson();
  });
  //show person based on current item
  function showPerson(){
    const item = reviews[currentItem];
    img.src = item.img;
    author.textContent = item.name;
    job.textContent = item.job;
    info.textContent = item.text;
    //get the next button working
    nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        currentItem++;
        if (currentItem > reviews.length - 1) {
          currentItem = 0;
        }
        showPerson();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just move nextBtn.AddEventListener to DOMContentLoaded and it works perfectly.

```js
const reviews = [

  {
    id: 1,
    name: "susan smith",
    job: "web developer",
    img: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883334/person-1_rfzshl.jpg",
    text: "I'm baby meggings twee health goth +1. Bicycle rights tumeric chartreuse before they sold out chambray pop-up. Shaman humblebrag pickled coloring book salvia hoodie, cold-pressed four dollar toast everyday carry",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "anna johnson",
    job: "web designer",
    img: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883409/person-2_np9x5l.jpg",
    text: "Helvetica artisan kinfolk thundercats lumbersexual blue bottle. Disrupt glossier gastropub deep v vice franzen hell of brooklyn twee enamel pin fashion axe.photo booth jean shorts artisan narwhal.",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "peter jones",
    job: "intern",
    img: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883417/person-3_ipa0mj.jpg",
    text: "Sriracha literally flexitarian irony, vape marfa unicorn. Glossier tattooed 8-bit, fixie waistcoat offal activated charcoal slow-carb marfa hell of pabst raclette post-ironic jianbing swag.",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "bill anderson",
    job: "the boss",
    img: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883423/person-4_t9nxjt.jpg",
    text: "Edison bulb put a bird on it humblebrag, marfa pok pok heirloom fashion axe cray stumptown venmo actually seitan. VHS farm-to-table schlitz, edison bulb pop-up 3 wolf moon tote bag street art shabby chic. ",
  },
];
//select items
const img = document.getElementById('person-img');
const author = document.getElementById('author');
const job = document.getElementById('job');
const info = document.getElementById('info');
//select buttons
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prev-btn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next-btn');
const randomBtn = document.querySelector('.random-btn');
//set starting item
let currentItem = 0; //as arrays start from zero                         
//load initial item
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  showPerson();
  //get the next button working
  nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    currentItem++;
    if (currentItem > reviews.length - 1) {
      currentItem = 0;
    }
    showPerson();
  });
});
//show person based on current item
function showPerson() {
  const item = reviews[currentItem];
  img.src = item.img;
  author.textContent = item.name;
  job.textContent = item.job;
  info.textContent = item.text;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <section class="container">
      <!-- title -->
      <div class="title">
        <h2>our reviews</h2>
        <div class="underline"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- review -->
      <article class="review">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="person-1.jpeg" id="person-img" alt="" width="100px" />
        </div>
        <h4 id="author">sara jones</h4>
        <p id="job">ux designer</p>
        <p id="info">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto asperiores debitis incidunt, eius earum ipsam cupiditate libero? Iste, doloremque nihil?
        </p>
        <!-- prev next buttons-->
        <div class="button-container">
          <button class="prev-btn">
              <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
            </button>
          <button class="next-btn">
              <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- random button -->
        <button class="random-btn">surprise me</button>
      </article>
    </section>
  </main>
  <!-- javascript -->
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```